# Probability of two variables of having the same value

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, uniform-distribution

Let $X$ and $Y$ be two random variables, whose PDFs $f_X$ and $f_Y$ are uniform. $f_X$ and $f_Y$ may overlap. For instance, they could represent two score distributions for two tuples $x$ and $y$ in a database.

Which is the probability for $X$ and $Y$ of having the same value $v$ (e.g., for the tuples $x$ and $y$ of having the same score)?

I have tried with an integral, but this returns me back $0$ as a result, since it is evaluated on an interval that is a point (the value $v$), and an integral that is evaluated on a point returns $0$ as a result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $X, Y$ are continuous it is indeed the case that $\text{Prob}(X=Y)=0$.

Comment: I agree (mathematically), but then I realized that if I have two objects $x$ and $y$, these two objects could have the same score. Thus, I don't get why the probability of this event to happen is exactly 0: I have a favorable case...

Comment: There is a difference in what we observe empirically and in the mathematical model that is supposed to model that phenomena. Our empirical observations often have limited precision and our models are often unrealistic. Thus, the observation that two objects have the same value does not necessarily mean that the mathematics is incorrect. Rather it could be that the measurements lack sufficient precision and the scores are really different or the model is not an accurate representation of the system.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you are right. If you set X and Y to be continuous r.v.'s, then the probability of getting the exact same value is 0 (because the integral of the density function from a point to the same point is always 0).

You could try an approximation by stating a range instead of a number. For example, you can ask what is the probability that both X and Y fall in the interval $(v - \epsilon, v + \epsilon)$, where $\epsilon$ is some small number (such as 0.005).